# Variable being updated but not being recognized PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Even though the variable is properly being changed by the if statements when a button is pressed, the original value is inputted. In the code, when a button is pressed, a value called pack is changed based on the input. The amount is based on this value. The button and $_POST are working properly, as well as the if statements because the respective values are being echoed. However, the $amount in the Stripe integration code uses the value used when the variable was created.

```
//Variable is set
$pack = 0;

if( isset( $_POST['moneyBTN'] )) {
    $pack = $_POST['package'];
}

 $amount = (int)$_POST['packages'];
//Stripe integration
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxx");
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "Buy",
    "source" => $token,
));
```

HTML

```
<form action="shop.php" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group input">
        <select name="package" class="form-control" id="select">       
          <option value="600">1</option>
          <option value="1000">2</option>
          <option value="1300">3</option>    
         </select>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="moneyBTN" value="Continue">
</form>

<form action="shop.php" method="post">
    <script 
          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="pk_test_FFqjZfFYCf32C51gmAhR2Ey6"
          data-amount=600
          data-name=Example
          data-description="Buy!"
          data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
          data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remove comma at the end of this line, `"source" => $token,` it should look like `"source" => $token`

Comment: When you echo `$amount` before the stripe integration, does it echo the correct value?

Comment: @Swellar Yes it does

Comment: Stripe takes zero decimal values so if you want to charge $10 your amount value should be 10*100= 1000. If your `$pack` value is perfect, it should work properly.

Comment: @jagad89I have edited the code to include the html and all of PHP

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why do you have two <form> tags?

Comment: @CriketX It's not a dumb question. Since the Stripe code created a new button, having them in the same form made the moneyBTN also display the Stripe modal. As I am a beginner at this, I found it to be the easiest way to separate them.

Comment: fair enough. you could just leave the <script> outside of a form and it'll be fine. What does $amount output when you echo it? I notice there are no "values" attached to your select menu.

Comment: @CriketX Oh thanks for that tip! Amount echoes the respective values it is assigned when I echo it. I'm running it based off of the value of select.

Comment: @apaul Note that you should _not_ trust an amount that's submitted by the client (unless the amount is explicitly set by the customer, e.g. if you're accepting donations), as it's trivial to change it. You should instead submit some form of ID (e.g. the package ID) and set the amount in your server-side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $amount = (int)$_POST['package']; //you had an 's' on 'packages' here.

    //Stripe integration
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $amount,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "description" => "Buy",
        "source" => $token,
    ));

    if($charge['success_message']) { //example, not working or tested
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'failure';
    }

} else { ?>

<form action="shop.php" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group input">
        <select name="package" class="form-control" id="select">       
            <option value="600">1</option> 
            <option value="1000">2</option> 
            <option value="1300">3</option>   
        </select>
    </div>
    <script 
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="pk_test_FFqjZfFYCf32C51gmAhR2Ey6"
      data-amount=600
      data-name=Example
      data-description="Buy!"
      data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
      data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: OK, I see you've changed your code now. Is it working?

Comment: Thanks, CriketX. I must have missed that. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: How do I then use the different values in the PHP code? Thanks

Comment: the `value` attribute is what actually get's passed through the $_POST method. Without it, it might be true (1) or false (0 or NULL)

Comment: That may have been one of the errors but it still doesn't work. I was wondering if this could be the cause: I have one button that when pressed sets the value of amount but I believe that buttons reload the page. The Stripe button is separate than the moneyBTN. Therefore, is it possible that the value of amount resets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155732/discussion-between-criketx-and-apaul).

Answer (score 1):

There is no value assigned in $pack variable so none of if statement is working. Change $pack variable into $_POST['pack']. Hope your code works well.

Comment: I should have included that in the code posted above as I have it in my code. I have tested the code and the if statements, as well as the $_POST values, are working correctly. The correct values were echoed. However, even though the $amount is changed above, it doesn't change in the Stripe Integration. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try clarifying your values in each option?

```
<select name="package" class="form-control" id="select">       
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>   
     </select>
```